# Why dubbo provider always registers to a wrong address?

Tags: apache-dubbo

I am running a sample of dubbo and the provider register to `192.168.1.100`.

I have change the `/etc/hosts` to nameserver and test it successfully. But when I start the provider it always register to the wrong address.

But the log shows that zk host is right. `address=zookeeper://114.116.xx.xx:2181`

```
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  INFO zookeeper.ZookeeperTransporter:  [DUBBO] No valid zookeeper client found from cache, therefore create a new client for url. zookeeper://114.116.xx.xx:2181/ConfigCenterConfig?address=zookeeper://114.116.xx.xx:2181&check=true&configFile=dubbo.properties&group=dubbo&highestPriority=false&namespace=dubbo&prefix=dubbo.config-center&timeout=3000&valid=true, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  WARN config.ConfigurationUtils:  [DUBBO] You specified the config centre, but there's not even one single config item in it., dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  WARN config.ConfigurationUtils:  [DUBBO] You specified the config centre, but there's not even one single config item in it., dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  WARN config.AbstractConfig:  [DUBBO] There's no valid metadata config found, if you are using the simplified mode of registry url, please make sure you have a metadata address configured properly., dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  INFO config.AbstractConfig:  [DUBBO] Export dubbo service cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService to local registry, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  INFO config.AbstractConfig:  [DUBBO] Export dubbo service cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService to url dubbo://192.168.1.100:20880/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService?anyhost=true&application=first-dubbo-provider&bind.ip=192.168.1.100&bind.port=20880&default.deprecated=false&default.dynamic=false&default.register=true&deprecated=false&dubbo=2.0.2&dynamic=false&generic=false&interface=cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService&methods=sayHello&pid=1064&register=true&release=2.7.1&side=provider&timestamp=1557935294228, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  INFO config.AbstractConfig:  [DUBBO] There's no valid monitor config found, if you want to open monitor statistics for Dubbo, please make sure your monitor is configured properly., dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:14:014 CST] main  INFO config.AbstractConfig:  [DUBBO] Register dubbo service cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService url dubbo://192.168.1.100:20880/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService?anyhost=true&application=first-dubbo-provider&bind.ip=192.168.1.100&bind.port=20880&default.deprecated=false&default.dynamic=false&default.register=true&deprecated=false&dubbo=2.0.2&dynamic=false&generic=false&interface=cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService&methods=sayHello&pid=1064&register=true&release=2.7.1&side=provider&timestamp=1557935294228 to registry registry://114.116.164.43:2181/org.apache.dubbo.registry.RegistryService?application=first-dubbo-provider&dubbo=2.0.2&pid=1064&registry=zookeeper&release=2.7.1&timestamp=1557935294217, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:15:015 CST] main  INFO server.Server:  [DUBBO] qos-server bind localhost:22222, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:15:015 CST] main  INFO transport.AbstractServer:  [DUBBO] Start NettyServer bind /0.0.0.0:20880, export /192.168.1.100:20880, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:15:015 CST] main  INFO zookeeper.ZookeeperRegistry:  [DUBBO] Load registry cache file C:\Users\I508530\.dubbo\dubbo-registry-first-dubbo-provider-114.116.164.43:2181.cache, data: {cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService=empty://192.168.1.100:20880/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService?anyhost=true&application=first-dubbo-provider&bind.ip=192.168.1.100&bind.port=20880&category=configurators&check=false&default.deprecated=false&default.dynamic=false&default.register=true&deprecated=false&dubbo=2.0.2&dynamic=false&generic=false&interface=cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService&methods=sayHello&pid=19372&register=true&release=2.7.1&side=provider&timestamp=1557935143900}, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:15:015 CST] main  INFO zookeeper.ZookeeperTransporter:  [DUBBO] find valid zookeeper client from the cache for address: zookeeper://114.116.164.43:2181/org.apache.dubbo.registry.RegistryService?application=first-dubbo-provider&dubbo=2.0.2&interface=org.apache.dubbo.registry.RegistryService&pid=1064&release=2.7.1&timestamp=1557935294217, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:15:015 CST] main  INFO zookeeper.ZookeeperRegistry:  [DUBBO] Register: dubbo://192.168.1.100:20880/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService?anyhost=true&application=first-dubbo-provider&default.deprecated=false&default.dynamic=false&default.register=true&deprecated=false&dubbo=2.0.2&dynamic=false&generic=false&interface=cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService&methods=sayHello&pid=1064&register=true&release=2.7.1&side=provider&timestamp=1557935294228, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:15:015 CST] main  INFO zookeeper.ZookeeperRegistry:  [DUBBO] Subscribe: provider://192.168.1.100:20880/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService?anyhost=true&application=first-dubbo-provider&bind.ip=192.168.1.100&bind.port=20880&category=configurators&check=false&default.deprecated=false&default.dynamic=false&default.register=true&deprecated=false&dubbo=2.0.2&dynamic=false&generic=false&interface=cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService&methods=sayHello&pid=1064&register=true&release=2.7.1&side=provider&timestamp=1557935294228, dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
[15/05/19 11:48:15:015 CST] main  INFO zookeeper.ZookeeperRegistry:  [DUBBO] Notify urls for subscribe url provider://192.168.1.100:20880/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService?anyhost=true&application=first-dubbo-provider&bind.ip=192.168.1.100&bind.port=20880&category=configurators&check=false&default.deprecated=false&default.dynamic=false&default.register=true&deprecated=false&dubbo=2.0.2&dynamic=false&generic=false&interface=cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService&methods=sayHello&pid=1064&register=true&release=2.7.1&side=provider&timestamp=1557935294228, urls: [empty://192.168.1.100:20880/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService?anyhost=true&application=first-dubbo-provider&bind.ip=192.168.1.100&bind.port=20880&category=configurators&check=false&default.deprecated=false&default.dynamic=false&default.register=true&deprecated=false&dubbo=2.0.2&dynamic=false&generic=false&interface=cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService&methods=sayHello&pid=1064&register=true&release=2.7.1&side=provider&timestamp=1557935294228], dubbo version: 2.7.1, current host: 192.168.1.100
```

The dubbo host should be `114.116.xx.xx` not `192.168.1.100`.

The zookeeper client shows wrong address, too.

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 1] ls /dubbo/cn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService/providers
[dubbo%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.100%3A20880%2Fcn.jcorn.dubbo.api.GreetingService
```

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the relevant network adapter. I solved this problem by disabling the loopback network adapter

Comment: Is the loopback network adapter on the Windows? I am using a ubuntu cloud server and found eth0 and lo.

Answer (score 0):

After running the code on Ubuntu, it works.

BTW, I edit the hosts to my hostname.